# Fonts and images source with Laravel Mix inside sub folder

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

im using Larverl 5.5 with Laravel Mix 1.0. All of my images are stored in public/images, fonts are in public/fonts. The problem is if my Laravel project is inside sub folder like htdocs/demo/laravel, all the images and fonts url cannot be found in scss files. For e.g:

app.scss

```
// Bootstrap
@import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";

// Font
@import "components/fonts";

// Font Awesome
@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";

wrapper {
  .banner {
    background: url('/images/banner.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    }
}
```

fonts.scss (inside fonts/components folder)

```
@font-face {
  font-family: MyFont;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url("/fonts/MyFont.eot");
  src: url("/fonts/MyFont.ttf") format("truetype"),
       url("/fonts/MyFont.woff") format("woff");
}
```

I also install font awesome and boostrap by npm and suffer the same problem with font.

Here is my webpack.mix.js

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

**Update 1:**
The problem with fonts was solve by add this to webpack.mix.js:

```
mix.setPublicPath('public/');
mix.setResourceRoot('../');
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Now the problem remains is the background image on scss file. It still points to "/images/banner.png" instead of "../images/banner.png" in app.css after run "npm run dev"

**Update 2:**
I was wrong, the problem with fonts still remain, only font awesome got correct path "../fonts", MyFont still points to "/fonts"

Comment: it has nothing to do  if you project is in sub folders,  set root of your project to `demo/laravel/public`

Comment: @lee manually change your url in public /app css  like this url(../fonts/MyFonts.eot)

Comment: @ Mahdi Younesi: how to set root?
@ bipin: i use npm run dev to build css from scss files, if i change to url(../images) in scss files, it will show error and cannot build css files

Comment: Could you show the full error?

Comment: @lee not in scss file I m talking about public folder app.css file

Answer (score 1):

Open your `webpack.mix.js` file inside the app folder and add these lines:

```
mix.setPublicPath('public');
mix.setResourceRoot('../');
```

And then run: `npm run dev`.

It will work.